# Allocate huge classes in virtual memory c++

Tags: c++, ios, memory-management, boost, virtual-memory

I have a class of size 2KB (which represents a node in a tree) and while my program runs, it allocates around 60,000 nodes which take up the memory to the tune of 120 MB.

I want to reduce this memory footprint for my app. For that I am trying to find a way so that the memory is allocated not in heap but somehow in the virtual memory.

I have looked at mmap files for this. However, I have the following doubts:

1. I looked at serialization of the class (using boost) to then store it in a memory mapped file. But the class is huge and serialization may not be possible
2. Then I came across basic_managed_shared_memory (again boost). But I can't figure out how to allocate new instances of my class in this managed memory. Any help here is also welcome.

So, my concern is how to allocate new instances of my class in the virtual memory with or without memory mapped files.

P.S.: The application would run on iOS.

Comment: Why not just store the objects in a NoSQL database? Only load what you need. You may have to be able to serialize the entire object, though.

Comment: "serialization may not be possible" Why not? Serialization should *always* be possible, if inconvenient.

Comment: You can use a high-performance key-value store database that supports iOS, for example [LMDB][1] (Lightning Memory-Mapped Database) to store your 2 KB nodes serialized. Serialization for 2 KB chunks should be fairly easy to archive.

Comment: or use a memory compression technique, if the data is not very random.

Comment: once you have the compression/database storage implemented, you will notice your device battery will drain faster. :-]

Comment: Perhaps this will give you some inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Votes&q=user%3a85371%20%20managed_shared_memory

Answer (score 0):

Iam not iOS programmer, but I'll write a platform independent response in the hope that this will help.

**First point:** 2KB * 60,000 nodes = 120 MB

*if you using standard allocators* - it is not true. Result size can be much bigger. This happen because standard allocators need hold many internal information to cover all options for its use.

*if you using own allocator* - it is can be true or not. It depends how implement own allocator. For example if using some kind of *linear allocator* and allocate object not in one operation, you can get some memory overhead(of course it will be less than standard allocator)

*if you using direct api call(mmap) for allocate all data by one operation* - In this case you will use native 120 MB.

**Second point:** Hold(or not) some data in external Database

As pointed in coments it can help for reducing virtual memory of application.

And you do not even need to store everything in the database. You can implement something like a swap mechanism, and keep in memory only what you need at the moment.

But be careful. Everything has its price. for exapmle if you will be often read/write data in database this can lead to cpu/battery utilization.

**Third point:** Some "tricks"

- if two nodes(or more) of tree can hold same information, you can
  allocate one node and reference to him in many places
- if in node some big byte sequence can be zero(or some other value) you can implement special data structure with typed chucnks. One of type of chuncks in this case can be small object which is treated as zero byte sequence.

**Fourth point** Heap/virtual memory, mmap, memory mapped files

According to my experience all task that require heavy memory usage, always doing by hand management by virtual memory api(mmap, VirtualAlloc). If you not need to shared you data not use *memory mapped files*.

**PS**

I wrote some general info about you problem, because you did not specify your task. If you give more information, maybe there is a solution for the ones that are more suitable for you